# How do I enable a prebuilt Siebel webservice ASI?

Tags: web-services, siebel

I am trying to do something rather simple. That is, using one of Siebel's prebuilt ASIs with a web service interface.

On the Siebel client, I navigated to "Inbound Web Services", and changed the status of one of the services to "Active".

I am using Siebel V 7.5.3

I import the WSDL file into SoapUI, and try to run the request, but still get the error:

> There is no active Web Service with operation named
>   'http://siebel.com/asi/:SiebelQuoteQueryById'.(SBL-EAI-04313)

Am I missing something? Could this be a permissions problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by restarting the server.

Navigate to "Server Administration" -> "Enterprise Operations". Use the bottom pane (the default displayed "Enterprise Servers" tab) to restart the server.